# How Exactly Does the Ghost of Christmas Present Work?

Tags: muppets, muppet-christmas-carol

I rewatched the Muppet Christmas Carol last night and was struck by the realism of the Ghost of Christmas Present.

[image]

I assume that this particular muppet is a man in a suit, a la Big Bird, but there's a few things I could not figure out.  Specifically, the eyelids open and close and the pupils move.

How did the Jim Henson company achieve this?  Or is it a closely guarded secret?

Answer (score 7):

G.o.c.Pr. is so large that it is a two person puppet. One controls the body while the other controlled the face and provided the voice. As large as he is, there is plenty of space in the face to add animatronics controls. No shots of the puppet in action are available.

Jerry Nelson was the voice/face and Don Austen the body.

Comment: Spot on CDE, Don austen also ended up doing the movement for the ghost of Christmas yet to come as well, with that puppet being so tall due to a fan keeping him cool (Don is my uncle)